# promiseの実行順序について

Tags: javascript, promise

現在promiseを使用して非同期なプログラムを書いています．

```
function wait() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("hey")
    }, 4000)
  })
}

function loop() {
  promiseList = []
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(function (index) {
      promiseList.push(wait())
    })
  //5回呼び出されるwait()プログラムのresolveを完了してからreturnしたい．
  return promiseList
}
```

## 問題

- loop()を呼び出すと，wait関数がresolveした関係なしに，5回ループするとpromiseListをreturnしてしまう．

## 理想動作

- wait関数が5回resolveされた後にreturnさせたい

## 環境

javascript
nodeは使用していない

Answer (score 1, accepted):

生成された`promiseList`はPromiseオブジェクトを要素とする単なる配列ですので、resolveを暗黙のうちに待ってくれたりはしません。[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)なるAPIを用いて、すべてのPromiseオブジェクトがresolveされたときresolveされる新たなPromiseオブジェクトを生成すれば、期待する動作が得られるでしょう(`op.1`)。
"理想動作"に関して、もしブロッキング動作をするような書き方を望まれるのであれば、`Promise`のシステムを使いやすく拡張した構文である[async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)を用いる必要があります(`op.2`)。この構文は古い処理系（ブラウザ・nodeなどのこと）では対応していない可能性があるので、対象の環境が対応しているか確認してください。

```js
function wait(idx) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(idx);
      resolve(`hey(${idx})`);
    }, 100)
  })
}

// op.1 use 'then' style
function loop() {
   return Promise.all([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(i => wait(i)));
}

// run
loop().then(ret => console.log(ret))

// op.2 use 'async/await' style
async function loop_2() {
    return await Promise.all([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(i => wait(2*i)));
}

// run
(async () => {
    const ret = await loop_2();
    console.log(ret);
})();

// 補足：今回の処理内容であれば、loop_2は冗長です
// runは次のように書いてもよい
(async () => {
    const ret = await loop();
    console.log(ret);
})();
```

Comment: op1の発想は僕にはなかったです．助かりました．ありがとうございます！！！